# Binding boolean (Property) to List operations in JavaFX

Tags: binding, kotlin, javafx-8, tornadofx

I found JavaFX to be suprisingly expressive after getting over the fact that I had to redeclare every field as property so I am a little stumped and would like to know if there is a better, more idomatic way of binding a boolean to some more complex operation like adding and removing style classes.

In this example I have a project that maybe valid or not and I want the font color of the tab to indicate which it is. I am doing this by adding and removing the error style class:

```
    val errorSwitch = { valid : Boolean ->
        logger.debug {"errorSwitcher: $valid"}
        if( valid) tab.styleClass.remove("error")
        else tab.styleClass.add("error")
        Unit
    }
    product.isValid.onChange (errorSwitch)
    errorSwitch(product.isValid.value)
```

What I don't like here is that I have to call the function once myself to start with because "onChange" obviously does not trigger unless the isValid actually changes. It's a small thing but I am wondering if there isn't a better way with bindings because thats what I want: the presence of the error class should be bound to "isValid"

Comment: There is no builtin way to do what you want, except when using `Bindings.bindBidirectional`. It is trivial to implement however, check out the `subscribe` method in [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind).

Comment: This Lib looks amazing, I will check it out, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TornadoFX the best way to achieve this is to use the `toggleClass` function, which will automatically add or remove a given class based on a boolean observable value. Therefore you can simply say:

```
tab.toggleClass(Styles.error, product.isValid)
```

This example requires you to use the Type Safe CSS feature of TornadoFX. Read more about Type Safe CSS in the guide :)

Comment: Hello Edvin, thanks again for your help. This would be excellent but unfortunately, I am not seeing this method on my javafx.scene.control.Tab object. It's probalby because I'm just instanciating it the plain old java/kotlin way from a controller. I'll try to factor it out so I can use the tornadofx builder.

Comment: This function is an extension function available from TornadoFX, so if you are indeed using TornadoFX (you tagged the question with the tornadofx tag, so I assumed) and you're writing Kotlin code, then you can use this function by importing `tornadofx.*`. If you're not using TornadoFX then I guess your initial solution is the best you can do :) hehe

Comment: sorry, yes I am definately using tornadofx (it's a lot of fun) but I think the problem is that Tab is not a Node. I can see the toggleClass function on other components, just not on tabs

Comment: Ah, you're right. We could probably move Node.toggleClass and friends to EventTarget. Will look into it ASAP!

Comment: I just committed spesific support for these on Tab :)